# apache locationmatch negative regex

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

I'm trying to expose a location through Apache.  Normally, I have this block in my vhost that says

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /web/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Test Site"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This works just fine - everything served up requires a valid user.  Now I want to expose a service that doesn't require authentication so I'm looking for a way to make all locations except for /services require authentication.  I've been playing with LocationMatch, but I'm not entirely clear on what it's doing.

```
<LocationMatch ^/(?!services)[^.]*$>
AuthType Basic
...
</LocationMatch>
```

Allows /services and everything beneath it to skip the LocationMatch, but it has the side-effect of allowing example.com/.somefile to bypass the LocationMatch block.

Additionally, when I tried

```
<LocationMatch ^/(?!services)>
AuthType Basic
...
</LocationMatch>
```

everything (including /services) is matched by the LocationMatch.

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what the [^.]* class does that the second test doesn't and how to expose only /services while keeping all other paths under authentication.

Answer (score 2):

[This page by Antonio Lorusso](http://antoniolorusso.com/2011/01/04/exclude-files-and-directories-from-apache-auth/) suggests the following to exclude folders from apache authentication:

```
<Location "/">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /var/www/clients/client12/web17/passwd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(admin|skin|js|index)(.*)$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/favicon.ico$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

In this case URLs starting with /admin, /skin, /js or /index will be ignored by auth.

The key part of this section for you is:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(admin|skin|js|index)(.*)$" allow
```

In your case the appropriate code would be:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/services(.*)$" allow
```

_

Answer (score 1):

Well, `[^.]` means "not a `.`", which is why `/.somefile` doesn't match.  A possible reason why your last example doesn't work is because Perl-compatible regular expressions are only supported starting with Apache 2.0, so if you're on Apache 1.3 (you really should specify an Apache version in your question), that'd be it.

Answer (score 1):

Mantain the

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic 
  AuthUserFile /web/.htpasswd
  AuthName "Test Site"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

and add a this new Location

```
<Location /services>
  Satisfy any
  Order deny,allow
</Location>
```

Comment: Does not work on apache 2.2

Comment: Locations must be on that order: first /, second /services. If applied the other way around, /services would be ignored

Comment: I tried in the both orders...
I was closed to abandon... 
And I found

Comment: This works for me on Apache 2.4, with the exception added after the password.

Answer (score 1):

With apache 2.4, you can do something like this:

```
<Location />
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/services/#">
        Satisfy any
        Order deny,allow
    </If>
    <Else>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /web/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Test Site"
        Require valid-user
    </Else>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried many ways without success.
And finally this works on apache 2.2.

- Two paths are unauthorized and others paths yes
- I added rewriting from / to /ui in order to make it possible

Hère is LocationMatch directive use

```
  <LocationMatch /(firstpath|secondpath).*>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted AREA "
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/security/password
            AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/security/group
            Require group admin
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
            Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
            Allow from env=allowclient

            Satisfy any
    </LocationMatch>
```